# Bootstrap modal/ jAlert alert not displayed in complete page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML page with frameset containing 2 frames. I would like to use Bootstrap modal/ jAlert alert in the complete page.

The normal JavaScript alert is displayed in complete page, but I would like modify its look with Bootstrap modal/ jAlert alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bit trickier than expected. You may need to create one main parent div that takes up 100% height and width, and then inside that main div add the 2 child divs or iframes like you have now with the frames. From there you can have the top parent div launch the Bootstrap modal which automatically position it in the middle of the screen by default.

Comment: I tried calling parent js function, but it still didn't show bootsrap alert. However normal alert are generated.

Comment: :When I used frameset it didnt work. That worked when when I started using Iframes.

Comment: Great! I revised my response to clarify. Can you accept the answer?